# Write text file from excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

New at C# using visual studio 2010 and trying to get output in a text file from an excel sheet. The excel sheet contains only one column with numeric values like this:

```
ColumnA
-------
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
877
566
767
678
767
```

I am trying to get the output in the text file like this:

```
222, 333, 444, 
555, 666, 777, 
888, 999, 877, 
566, 767, 678,
767
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying to do using C#. Please help.

Comment: Use the [Excel Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx) to get access to the excel file, then format and write it to your file in C#. Also, remember Excel cells are 1-based indexes, rather than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it using the [BytesCout SpreadSheet SDK](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/bytescoutspreadsheetsdk.html):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Bytescout.Spreadsheet;

namespace Converting_XLS_to_TXT
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
// Create new Spreadsheet from SimpleReport.xls file
Spreadsheet document = new Spreadsheet("SimpleReport.xls");

// delete output file if exists already
if (File.Exists("SimpleReport.txt")){
File.Delete("SimpleReport.txt");
}

// save into TXT
document.Workbook.Worksheets[0].SaveAsTXT("SimpleReport.txt");

}
}
}
```

**References:**

- [BytesCout SpreadSheet Tutorial](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/bytescoutxls_convert_excel_xls_into_text_txt_file.html)

Comment: he want to write that to text file. I think Datalist with repeat column is correct control to display this data in required format on webpage and not gridview